# Calculating $\cos(1.1)$ with an absolute error smaller than $10^{-4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, numerical-methods

My goal is to calculate $\mathrm{cos(1.1)}$ with an absolute error smaller than $\mathrm{10^{-4}}$ using the following relations:

> $\mathrm{cos^{2}(x)+sin^{2}(x)=1}$

> $\mathrm{sin(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}}$

I could try using that $\mathrm{cos^2(x)=(1-sin(x))(1+sin(x))}$ and assure that each factor has an absolute error smaller than $\mathrm{10^{-8}}$. Is this approach valid? If not, how should this question be answered?

Comment: Why don't you directly use cosine's Taylor series?

Comment: If you insist on going this route (rather than following the above suggestion by sreysus), I would still choose not to factor $1-\sin^2(x)$. It is marginally easier to control the absolute error of $\sin^2x$ in terms of the error of $\sin x$ than it is to control the absolute error of $(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)$.

Comment: Do the Taylor expansion around $x_0=\frac\pi3\approx 1.05$ for faster convergence.